# How can I use angularjs $parse service in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript, angular-services

I'm trying to migrate the $parse function in angularjs to angular, but I don't know how to convert it.

```
var getters = [];
angular.forEach(expressions, function parseExpression(expression) {
            getters.push($parse(expression));
        });
```